# My computer still freezes after installing new RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze

I've been having this freezing issue for weeks now and I can't take it any more. My computer occasionally will freeze, not randomly, but only when I do an action like open a new tab. I thought for sure this was a memory issue. I ran memtest86 and sure enough there were errors on a few tests. I have 4x 4GB cards installed so I took 2 out and kept testing. Of course it would still freeze and I would try different pairs of cards. None worked. I've had this RAM for 5 years now and was reading reviews that these crap out around that time. I figured maybe all 4 are bad and bought a new pair of the same type of RAM. I only have these 2 new ones in. At first it seemed like it was working, but then it eventually froze and now it keeps freezing as bad as the others.

When my computer freezes, I have to do a hard reset by holding the power button and turning it back on. If a sound was playing, then the freeze would play the last played sound in an annoying millisecond loop.

I'm thinking about replacing the CPU, motherboard, or PSU in that order.

I'm also considering the possibility of a software error where maybe a running application is causing it to freeze. I don't see anything in my Event logs though, only that there was a bad shutdown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the memtest with the new sticks? It could be the slot that is bad.

Comment: No I didn't but I'll do that now

Comment: Not showing any errors on the first pass so I stopped it

Comment: I think you were right about the slot being bad. I moved my 2 new sticks over to the other side's pair and it's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the problem of RAM,

This may be the problem of your HHD, Try replacing HHD with SSD..

To confirm open task manager first and then try to do the task that freezes your pc.

If your disk went 100% then this may be the problem of your HHD.

Thankx....

Comment: I am already running this on a SSD. However, does that give me the idea to maybe try new SATA cables. I also have another SSD but it has all my backups. I'll see what I can do